# Are IDS/IPS already implemented on Google Cloud?

Tags: ids, confidentiality

I have a partner that is asking "Do you use breach detection/prevention tools?".

I host my service on managed hosting (Heroku) and currently migrating to Google Cloud. Should I be using ["breach detection/prevention tools"](https://cloud.google.com/intrusion-detection-system) or is that already handled/managed by Heroku or Google Cloud?

Comment: You mean, like this? https://cloud.google.com/intrusion-detection-system

Comment: If you're a google cloud customer it might be worth it to ask Google to clarify

Comment: If you don't know whether or not you use these tools, then it seems like the answer is "no." How can you being using tools that you don't already know whether or not you use?